# javascript regular expression for domain validation doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, regex, safari

I have no idea why safari says error for this javascript regular expression.

```
^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,63}$
```

just a validation of domain and I got error in this part `(?<!-)` domain name shouldn't end with hyphen.

I don't know the details but it's sounds likes safari doesn't support negative behind.

I do need some help for my problem.

Comment: lookbehind is not yet widely supported. I am unsure, whether safari does, but wouldn't be surprised, if it didn't.

Comment: thanks guys,,,what should I do for my situation, I want to fix this `(?<!-)`

Comment: I am not sure you needed that piece since you are making sure you are going to have at least 1 `{1,63}` and you are also making sure at the beginning with negative forward look to not to have `-` , so I feel you don't need `(?<!-)` all together. Try and see .

Comment: @JBone
without this `(?<!-)` domain name will end with hyphen, like this `google-.com`

Comment: oh yea. ok. you are correct.

Comment: Why do you want to make that check? If you want to check if the domain provided is valid, just try to ping it and check the return value.

Comment: Convert to a "far-looking" lookahead: `^(?!.*-\.)((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,63}$`

Comment: Ping can be disabled and domain still being correct.

Comment: Please check my answer below and let know if there is anything unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+` part in your regex is meant to match 1 to 63 character chunks followed by a dot that consist of ASCII letters or digits or hyphens but that do not start nor end with a hyphen. While the `(?!-)` negative lookahead is fine to use in JS ES5 compliant regex, the `(?<!-)` lookbehind is not supported there.

So, a solution would be to perform a check for `-.` sequence in the string at the very start and if the sequence is found, fail the whole match:

```
^(?!.*-\.)(?:(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,63}$
 ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HpCHWP/1).

If you are worried about the performance and backtracking involved with the `.*-\.` pattern you may replace `(?!.*-\.)` with `(?![^-]*(?:-(?!\.)[^-]*)*-\.)`, see [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HpCHWP/2).